# Excel VBA to Execute Stored UNION Query from MS Access 2003

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, union, ado

I'm writing a function in Excel VBA to execute a stored queries on a database created using MS Access 2003. The code works when the stored query is a simple query, but NOT if the query is a `UNION`. For example, I'm using the following code to execute the stored queries:

```
Public Function QueryDB()

    Dim cn As Object

    Dim strConnection As String
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    ' Hard code database location and name
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\server1\myDatabase.mdb"

    ' Open the db connection
    cn.Open strConnection

    ' Create call to stored procedure on access DB
    Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "testQuery"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

    ' Execute stored query
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = cmd.Execute()

    MsgBox rs.Fields(0) ' prints as expected

    QueryDB2 = rs.Fields(0)


    ' close connections
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Function
```

If `testQuery` is a simple query (e.g., does not use `UNION`), then data is returned as expected. However, if the `testQuery` contains a `UNION`, then the Excel VBA code fails (and no particular error is returned). How can I work-around this issue? I'd like to avoid writing the SQL statement in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using ADO's [Open Recordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. Usually, [Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are for action commands (append/update/delete, stored procedures, etc.). Additionally, if Execute returns a recordset it is only a forward-only (i.e, snapshot with no cursor), read-only recordset without the facilities of `MoveNext`, `RecordCount`, `Update`.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rst As Object

Dim strConnection As String
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' Hard code database location and name
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\server1\myDatabase.mdb"

' Open the db connection
cn.Open strConnection
' Open the recordset
rst.Open "testQuery", cn

Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

' Close recordset and db connection
rst.Close
cn.Close
```

Comment: Again, this unfortunately works only for regular queries and not for queries containing a UNION statement.

Comment: Very interesting as I tested above with a union query to be sure. Can you post your union SQL query and maybe even sample data?

Comment: Even though this query doesn't make sense, it is still the simplest I could think of, and it does not work. `SELECT * FROM myTable UNION SELECT * FROM myTable;`. I've saved this query in my database, and when trying to access the resultset in Excel, VBA returns the Run-time error, *"Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."*

Comment: Check if you are using a [reserved Access word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx) as a column alias from any table in union query. Common ones are: `Date`, `Name`, `No`.

Comment: Literally this fails for me when my query is `SELECT Account FROM EM_Daily_Acc_Data_ex_cur UNION SELECT Account FROM EM_Daily_Acc_Data_ex_cur;` The table does contain a column named "Date" though.

Comment: I ran into your issue only with an improperly named stored query in `rst.Open` line. Check spelling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98744/discussion-between-nsw-and-parfait).

Comment: Thank you, @Parfait. It looks like there may have been a few factors contributing to this error. 1) The query name may not contain a dash. 2) The SQL statement may not contain the MS Access function, IIF(exp, val, val). 3) The "Date" column name may have also been an issue (even though I assigned an alias to the column), which I've changed to "DataDate." Thank you for the help.

Comment: if it's not too much trouble, would you mind editing your answer to demonstrate executing queries that require parameter inputs? For example, where the parameter value is in Sheet1!A1. Will I need a new ADODB.Command objects?

Answer (score 1):

Are you still struggling with this?  Try using an ODBC Query.  Follow the steps listed here.

http://translate.google.pl/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=pl&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=pl&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fafin.net%2FKsiazkaSQLwExcelu%2FGraficznyEdytorZapytanSqlNaPrzykladzieMsQuery.htm

Make sure you have no nulls in your Union and if you do, you must use the NZ Function to convert nulls into zeros.

Comment: `NZ()` will fore sure break the interoperability of the query. Recommended alternative is `IIF( someField IS NULL, someReturnVal, someField)`.  
Why ? see http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html